# Jquery page does not fully load/display

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery mobile page that has couple of links in it. The problem is that, when I click on a button to go to the next page, all the elements do not fully show (e.g footer and some others). I have to refresh the page before I can see the full content. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <body data-role="body">
  <header data-role="header">
     <a href=""  data-role="button"  data-transition="fade" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <a href="base.php" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="fade" data-icon="home">Home</a>

    <?  require'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
</header>


<div data-role="content" id="basecontent">
    <a href="#" id="profile" data-transition="fade" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Create A profile</a>
    <a id="findshuttle" href="shuttleview.php" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Find the Shuttle</a>
    <a id="where" href="whereami.php"  data-transition="fade" data-role="button">where am I</a>
</div>

</body>
 <?  require'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

It sounds like I did not ask the question well. Lets say I go to www.foo.com everything loads well but if I navigate to foo.com/bass the page partially gets loaded. If reload foo.com/bass, everything gets rendered but if I try to go back to foo.com, the page partially loads.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to the point where you start invaliding answers below.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've got posted here, it appears as if your navbar is in the of your document and your footer is below the closing tag. Those elements will not show if they are not inside the open tag of your page.

```
<body data-role="body">
<header data-role="header">
<a href=""  data-role="button"  data-transition="fade" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>
<h1>App</h1>
<a href="base.php" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="fade" data-icon="home">Home</a>
</header>
    <!--Move this below header-->
<?  require'includes/navbar.php'; ?>

<div data-role="content" id="basecontent">
<a href="#" id="profile" data-transition="fade" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Create A profile</a>
<a id="findshuttle" href="shuttleview.php" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Find the Shuttle</a>
<a id="where" href="whereami.php"  data-transition="fade" data-role="button">where am I</a>
</div>
    <!--Move this above closing body tag-->
<?  require'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks sounds like I did not ask the question well. Lets say I go to www.foo.com everything loads well but if I navigate to foo.com/bass the page partially gets loaded. If reload foo.com/bass, everything gets rendered but if I try to go back to foo.com, the page partially loads.

Comment: With the information you provided, I can't explain why it would ever work because generally elements outside of the body tags are not shown to the end user. I'm not really clear on how dynamic these pages are, do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Note: Best practice is to use long PHP tags, not short ones -- ie use `<?php` rather than just `<?`.